# How to calculate driving distance/time between two points

Tags: arcgis-10.1, distance, network-analyst, routing, transportation

I am doing some analysis for our fire rescue department where we are comparing actual response times to fires vs predicted response times.

The actual response time analysis is straight forward as I have the data and have created the charts.

The predicted response time analysis is a little trickier and what I'm a little unsure about. Essentially, we need to determine the driving distance from the closest 3 fire stations to each fire, and then determine the response time from each station to the fire driving at 40mph.

I have network analyst and can assume this is what I'll need to use (arcgis 10.1).

There are roughly 480 fires I need to do this with so I'm looking for a way to do this programatically, if possible.

Is it as easy as getting a total distance in one field and then creating another field that calculates distance x speed?

Comment: Do you need to account for congestion, road closures, lack of capacity? Or are you strictly calculating travel times assuming no congestion and nothing bad is going to happen?

Answer (score 2):

if you have Network analyst, you can use "OD cost matrix". Your case is indeed quite simple because the time is directly proportional to the travelled distance.